# spring AOP error at 0 can't find referenced pointcut

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

I am using Java 8, spring 4.3 and AspectJ 1.8.9. Why I am getting the below error for the below code. If I use the @Before("com.beans.Student.addCustomer()") without pointcut I am getting this error at 0 can't find referenced pointcut. When using @Before with a pointcut I am not getting the error.

Beans:

```
@Aspect
public class Beforeaspect {

    /*
     * @Pointcut("execution(* com.beans.Student.addCustomer(..))") public void
     * log(){
     * }
     */

    // @Before("log()")
    @Before("com.beans.Student.addCustomer()")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint jp) {
        System.out.println("logbefore");
        System.out.println("method " + jp.getSignature().getName());
    }
}
```

Student:

```
package com.beans;

public class Student implements Studentimpl {

    public void addCustomer() {
        System.out.println("addcustomer");
    }

    public String addCustomername(String stud) {
        System.out.println("addcustomername");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Spring xml file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd">
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    <bean id="stud" class="com.beans.Student" />
    <bean class="com.beans.Beforeaspect" />
</beans>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong syntax used for the method execution. Your annotation should be:

```
@Before("execution(* com.beans.Student.addCustomer(..))")
public void logBefore(JoinPoint jp) {
    System.out.println("logbefore");
    System.out.println("method " + jp.getSignature().getName());
}
```

Or use the XML Bean:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

<bean id="logAspect" class="nch.spring.aop.aspectj.LoggingAspect" />

<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="aspectLoggging" ref="logAspect">
        <aop:pointcut id="pointCutBefore" expression="execution(* com.beans.Student.addCustomer(..)))" />
        <aop:before method="logBefore" pointcut-ref="pointCutBefore" />
    <aop:aspect/>
<aop:config>
```

Comment: Thanks Nikolas, I forgot to add the belowpublic class Student{

 @Pointcut("execution(* com.beans.Student.addCustomers(..))")
 void addCustomer(){
  
 }
}